# Função similar a matlabfunction() do MATLAB em R

Tags: r, matlab

Existe uma função similar à `matlabFunction()` do MATLAB? Ou como fazer isso em `R`?

A função em MATLAB.

```
syms x
dados = inputdlg({'P(x): ', 'Q(x): ', 'R(x): ', 'N: '},'Dados');
P = matlabFunction(sym(dados{1}),'vars',x,'file','px');
```

Em `R` estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
P <- function(x){
   expr = dados[1]
   y <- eval(parse(text= expr), list(x))
   return (y)
}
```

Porém ainda tenho que mudar a expressão dentro da função ou passar ela por parâmetro.

Comment: O que essa função faz no matlab?

Comment: Converte expressão simbólica para uma função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Matlab a função `inline` é equivalente a função `matlabFunction()`  e em `R` o comando  `function` pode ser utilizado pra criar as mesmas funcionalidades.

Utilizando ambas as funções em Matlab para provar similaridade:

```
f1 = inline('sin(x/3) - cos(x/5)')

f1 =

     Inline function:
     f1(x) = sin(x/3) - cos(x/5)
```

---

```
f2 = matlabFunction(sin(x/3) - cos(x/5))

f2 = 

    @(x)-cos(x.*(1.0./5.0))+sin(x.*(1.0./3.0))
```

---

Chamando `f1` e `f2` para computar e provar que seno(2/3) - cosseno(2/5) é igual a -0,3027 em qualquer uma das funções:

```
f1(2)

ans =

   -0.3027

f2(2)

ans =

   -0.3027
```

Agora a mesma função criada de forma similar em `R`:

```
f <- function(x) sin(x/3) - cos(x/5)
f(2) 
-0.3026912
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
make.Rfunction <- function(expressao) {
    fn <- function(x) {
        return(eval(parse(text= expressao), list(x)))
    }
return(fn)
}

dados <- c("x+2")
P <- make.Rfunction(dados[1])
P(2) # resposta : [1] 4
P(3) # resposta : [1] 5
```